# Aside from the exponential family, where else can conjugate priors come from?

Tags: bayesian, exponential-family, conjugate-prior

Do **all** conjugate priors have to come from the exponential family? If not, what other families are known to have/produce conjugate priors?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As explained for example in Section 3.3.3 of book "The Bayesian choice" by Christian Robert, there is indeed a narrow connection between exponential families and conjugate priors, but there are conjugate priors available for certain non-exponential families. He calls these "quasi-exponential", however, because they are families for which sufficient statistics of finite dimension not increasing with sample size do exist.

Here is an example for the uniform distribution, whose support depends on the parameter of the distribution and can therefore not be an exponential family (as is well-known):

Here, the Pareto distribution is a conjugate prior for the parameter $b$ of the uniform distribution on $[0,b]$.

The density of the Pareto distribution with parameters $c>0$ and $%
\alpha >0$ is
\begin{equation*}
f(x)=\alpha c^{\alpha }x^{-\alpha -1}
\end{equation*}
for $x\geq c$ and $f(x)=0$ else.

The prior of the parameter $b$ of a uniform distribution on $[0,b]$ is a Pareto distribution with $c_{0}$ and $\alpha _{0}$,
\begin{eqnarray*}
\pi (b) &=& \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
\alpha _{0}c_{0}^{\alpha _{0}}b ^{-\alpha _{0}-1} & \quad \text{if }
b \geq c_{0} \\
0 & \quad \text{else.}%
\end{array}
\right. \\
&\propto &\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
b ^{-\alpha _{0}-1} & \quad \text{if }b \geq c_{0} \\
0 & \quad \text{else.}%
\end{array}%
\right.
\end{eqnarray*}
The likelihood for the data $y_{1},\ldots ,y_{n}$, given $b$, is
\begin{equation*}
f\left( y |b\right) = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
\prod_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{b }=b ^{-n} & \quad \text{if }0\leq
y_{i}\leq b \text{ for all }i=1,\ldots ,n \\
0 & \quad \text{else.}%
\end{array}%
\right.
\end{equation*}
The product of likelihood and prior is the non-normalized posterior
\begin{eqnarray*}
\pi \left( b |y\right) &\propto &\pi (b )f\left( y |b\right)
\\
&=&\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
\alpha _{0}c_{0}^{\alpha _{0}}b ^{-\alpha _{0}-1}b ^{-n} & \quad
\text{if }b \geq c_{0}\text{ and }0\leq y_{i}\leq b \text{ for all
}i=1,\ldots ,n \\
0 & \quad \text{else.}%
\end{array}%
\right. \\
&\propto &\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
b ^{-\alpha _{0}-n-1} & \quad \text{if }b \geq c_{0}\text{ and }%
0\leq y_{i}\leq b \text{ for all }i=1,\ldots ,n \\
0 & \quad \text{else.}%
\end{array}%
\right. \\
&\propto &\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
b ^{-\alpha _{1}-1} & \quad \text{if }b \geq c_{1} \\
0 & \quad \text{else.}%
\end{array}%
\right.
\end{eqnarray*}
with
\begin{eqnarray*}
\alpha _{1} &=&\alpha _{0}+n \\
c_{1} &=&\max\bigl(\max_{i}y_{i},c_0\bigr).
\end{eqnarray*}
Hence, the posterior is Pareto distributed.

Comment: (+1) So iff there's a sufficient statistic of constant dimension, there's a conjugate prior?

Comment: Very interesting question - I do not know! My answer just provides an example that membership of an exponential family is not a necessary condition for the existence of a conjugate prior. I would be very interested in the answer, so please ask this as a separate question!

Comment: I've a feeling it's got to be so for updating to work. I'll certainly ask a question if I can't find a book answer.

Comment: @Scortchi: yes indeed, because if there exists a sufficient statistic of fixed dimension _then_ we are in an exponential family, as established by the [Pitman-Koopman-Darmois](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sufficient_statistic#Exponential_family) lemma.

Comment: Does this not omit the qualifier: "among all families whose support does not depend on the parameter", see also the above example?

Comment: @Scortchi did you ask that follow-up question, and/or learn the answer elsewhere? I'll ask it myself if not.

Comment: @Scortchi-ReinstateMonica I've asked the question in your comment as a new Question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/513705/does-a-sufficient-statistic-imply-the-existence-of-a-conjugate-prior)

Comment: @Nathaniel: Thanks! Sorry I missed your previous comment.