# Conjugate Prior for Student T distribution

Tags: t-distribution, conjugate-prior

Does the Student T distribution have a conjugate prior distribution? If so, what is it and what are the parameters?

Comment: No, the Student's $t$ distribution is not an exponential family and therefore cannot have a conjugate prior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please see page 19 in this link:
https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jordan/courses/260-spring10/other-readings/chapter9.pdf

In general it says the Student's t distribution is not an exponential family and therefore cannot have a conjugate prior. The fact that the Student's $t$ distribution cannot enjoy a conjugate family (other than the trivial collection of all probability distributions) over the parameter space is connected with the [Darmois-Pitman-Koopman lemma.](https://xianblog.wordpress.com/2017/11/15/darmois-koopman-and-pitman/)

Comment: Re "the Student's t distribution is not an exponential family and therefore cannot have a conjugate prior": https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/192554/aside-from-the-exponential-family-where-else-can-conjugate-priors-come-from/192675#192675

Comment: Are there any citable papers stating that the mean to a $t$-distribution does not have a conjugate prior?

Answer (score 0):

Student t-distribution does not have conjugate prior for the degrees of the freedom. However, even so, there are several priors that could be used for the degrees of the freedom.

https://www.mdpi.com/2075-1680/11/9/462

Comment: Please, consider expanding your answer. As it is, this seems more like a comment than an answer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).